# Index are not listing in sitecore 9.1

Tags: solr

I have installed fresh sitecore 9.1 instance in local environment. There is no issue with installation but i couldn't see any indexes in Index manager. All the configurations are enabled and i even verified by login into solr instance. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Your core names in your config do not match the core names in solr. Did you replace you configs? Looks for all configs with solr in the name. Check the core name.

Comment: Assuming your solr instance and up and running. Have you populated Solr Managed Schema? To do so go to control pagel and click:"Populate Solr Managed Schema"

Comment: A slash at the end of Solr.url attribute in connection string is another possible reason in Sitecore not able to connect with Solr.

Answer (score 5):

Please check following things:

1. Verify that Solr is up and running
2. Solr.url attribute in connection string shall have correct Solr url
3. Open the `/Sitecore/Admin/showconfig.aspx` and search for `sitecore_master`, it should show Solr core name. The actual config is present at `Webroot\App_Config\Sitecore\ContentSearch\Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Master.config`. If not present, add the configs manually. Repeat the steps for other cores.
4. Check Solr having required cores (11 cores like Sitecore_master_index) or not. If not create the cores.
5. After that place schema files in all cores
6. Restart the Solr and iisreset the Website
7. After login check indexing manager

Comment: For me inside the config  file of the respective index the core param name was wrong.
<param desc="core">$(id)</param> - Here instead of id it was a custom name which didn't exist. 
Have a look into this, you never know!

Comment: If it's XP single topology then name of Solr index present and in case of XP scaled id should be present.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue that no indexes are shown in the Sitecore indexing manager. I verified the Solr console and all the cores were loading fine there. I have identified after some time that `ContentSearch.Enabled` was set to *false* in `Sitecore.ContentSearch.config` . Changed this setting to true and tried connecting the indexes. it started coming.

Basically, Just go to this path, *`<cm_root>\App_Config\Sitecore\ContentSearch\Sitecore.ContentSearch.config`* and search this setting and make sure this is *true*.

```
<setting name="ContentSearch.Enabled" value="true" />
```